# Can users request any of the following criteria (Cracks/Activators)

Tags: discussion, questions, disallow-tag

Is It possible to ask for any programs such as Windows operating system activators And cracks or any software activator on this forum?

Comment: Its a dupe. Oddly enough 2 of the mods have pretty opposite views to it, but I'd *strongly discourage* such questions.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I think my question seems to be too wide :D too many opinions but thanks ! :)

Comment: Well, my own opinion is absolutely not. At the very least though I would suspect 99% of such questions would be low quality - so many of these questions would be closed anyway. Many of these cracks/hacks get patched so the answers are transient and may not help future folk so many answers would be obsolete eventually.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I would agree that it might be Low-Quality,also at the same time answering those type of questions will face legal problems I guess ? as this site operates under the law.

Comment: In short, more trouble than its worth, but will be handled on a case by case basis.

Comment: To clarify Journeyman's previous comment; my personal view on the subject is that **piracy is wrong.** It's theft, etc... But as a user, I don't think that we should be making judgement calls based on our perception of the author's motives. That pretty much sums up my views :)